# What are other modern, free analogs of Squeak and Esterel?

Tags: c, concurrency, embedded, squeak

A long time ago, Rob Pike and Luca Cardelli wrote a [paper](http://doc.cat-v.org/bell_labs/squeak/) called "Squeak: a language for communicating with mice". It was based on Hoare's communicating sequential processes, but it was compiled into single-threaded C code - no threads or scheduler at runtime. However, I can't find a compiler for Squeak, and Rob Pike went on to write [newsqueak](http://herpolhode.com/rob/), which does have a nondeterministic scheduler at runtime, and so isn't what I want.

Esterel is also a language with a lot of support for concurrency, which can be compiled into single-threaded C code - but Esterel Technologies sells SCADE Studio for so much money, they won't even say how much it costs on their [web page](http://www.esterel-technologies.com/).

The Columbia Esterel Compiler is [available](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/cec/). Are there other modern languages that compile "multi-threaded" algorithms into single-threaded, deterministic output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you looking for programming languages with deterministic concurrency models?

If so, the canonical example would be the [Mozart Programming System](http://WWW.Mozart-Oz.Org/), based on the Distributed Oz Programming Language.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation of Esterel, called Lustre is available upon request at http://www-verimag.imag.fr/SYNCHRONE/index.php?page=lv4-distrib

It asks for a signed license, but I just e-mailed Pascal Raymond and he sent me link to download the source code.

It works, but it takes a little patience getting it set up. Thinking about making an Automake script to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [signal language](http://www.irisa.fr/espresso/Polychrony/download.php), that belongs to [Synchronous languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_programming_language) family ?